# Windows 10 Remote Audio hibernation?

Tags: windows-10, audio, remote-desktop, lag

I have a windows 10 pc that I remote into using Remote Desktop (RDP).

The pc is on the same network, and the response is great. When I play a youtube movie even over the RDP connection, its all going fast and everything.

However, if there hasn't been played sound for a while, the Remote Audio device seems to go in some kind of hibernation. Sound is queued up and there's no sound coming. Videos can't play back until the device is restored, and once it is, the queued sounds start to play again all at once and all is fine again. The sound is laggy/distorted too.

On the windows 10 computer, I've changed the policy to always set audio to high quality, and did the same on the client side but it is not fixing the issue.

Now here is the strangest part of all. If I start XMPlay and stream an online radio, everything audiowise is fine. No distortions etc. In fact, if I let it play, but set the volume to 0, all audio is fine too, no distortions or stutters or whatever. I can even play a silent wave form on loop in the background and it is fine, but when I stop XMPlay, immediately after, sound starts to lag again, as if some kind of powersaving mode is in effect.

The Power Options is set to High Performance.

Anyone any idea how to solve this?